# Function pointers, arrays and lvalues in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's suppose that we have the following functions (in C):

```
int sum(int a, int b){  
   return a+b;
}
int diff(int a, int b){
    return a-b;
}
```

So we know that we can declare an array of funtion pointers in the following way:

```
int (*test[2]) (int a, int b);
test[0] = sum;
test[1] = diff;
```

But the following is also valid (but we use heap allocation):

```
int (**test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
test[0] = sum;
test[1] = diff;
```

So far so good. Now let remember that to declare a (dynamically allocated) array of two integers we can do:

```
 int* test  = malloc( 2*sizeof(int));
```

So why we cannot declare an array of function pointers as

```
int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test)); ?
```

**Is the reason that as test is the same as `*test` and `**test` (and so on), `malloc( 2*sizeof(*test))` is returning a pointer to a function pointer and therefore it cannot be assigned to `(*test)` ?**

If this supposition is correct, can you explain in **detail** why we get the compilation error

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

when we try to do

```
int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
test=diff; //<--- This is ok.
test+1 = sum; //<--- This is what gives the error!
```

Disclaimer: I suppose that this is a basic question and the supposition is correct, but I would like a better explanation to have this kind of thing clear one and for all.

---

Edit:

Notice that this is equivalent to

```
int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
*test=*diff; //<--- This is ok.
*(test+1) = *sum; //<--- This is what gives the error!
```

as this is somewhat more similar to the case:

```
int *test = malloc(2*sizeof(*test));
*test = 0;
*(test+1) = 1;
```

Comment: Because you cannot bit-copy functions in C, there is no way to get a contiguous array of two functions, which is why `int(*)()` cannot be an array. `test+1` is invalid probably because functions do not have a fixed size, so it doesn't know how many bytes to increment the pointer by.

Comment: `int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));` is also not correct.

Comment: @this Yeah, I know, but as it does not make the compiler angry I want to know what is going on at compiler time. Sorry if the question is basic but this kind of things give me night terrors. :)

Comment: And your functions aren't correct either, they should return values.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will edit that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So why we cannot declare an array of function pointers as
>
> ```
> int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
> ```

Because `test` does not point to a function pointer; it *is* a function pointer. Thus it cannot point to the first element of an array of function pointers.

If you want an array of function pointers use the previous form:

> ```
> int (**test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
> ```

Here, `*test` has function pointer type and thus `test` can (and does) point to the first element of an array of function pointers. Further:

> ```
> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
> ```
>
> when we try to do
>
> ```
>  int (*test) (int a, int b) = malloc( 2*sizeof(*test));
>  test=diff; //<--- This is ok.
>  test+1 = sum; //<--- This is what gives the error!
> ```

No matter what type `test` has, `test+1=anything` is always invalid C. `test+1` can never be an lvalue. I don't see why you would expect this to work.

GCC is also papering over another bug in your program, `sizeof(*test)`. Since `*test` has function type, `sizeof(*test)` is invalid, but GCC silently assigns it the value 1. This results in allocating too little memory for a function pointer, but it doesn't matter anyway because in the following line you throw away the memory you got from `malloc` and assign something else to `test`.

Comment: The thing is that when you declare a function, the NAME of the function is itself a function pointer and therefore I suppose that there is no way to connect with the pointer-to-array-of-ints case. But I want to know more about the difference between the two cases. Thank you for your great answer, by the way. :)

Comment: I have added a little sub-question to the main question as an edit. Thank you!

Comment: Its false to say the name "is" a pointer. It's not. It just "decays" to a pointer in most contexts the same way an array name does. However this does not happen when it's the operand of the `&` or `sizeof` operators.